# Cv2 install not working, among other problems

Tags: python, windows, numpy, opencv

I was exporting pygame project as a .exe file, and when I ran it I got an error. I discovered, due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50948054/opencv-function-read-return-false-none-in-remote-environment)  and other posts, that multiple things in my code were coming up as 'None' and my filetype may not be supported.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("C:/Users/Molly/OneDrive/Desktop/New folder (2)/VIDEOOO.mp4")

success, img = cap.read()
shape = img.shape[1::-1]
wn = pygame.display.set_mode(shape)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

I did what that post said, it was, in fact, unsupported. And re-installed cv2. I then got this error in my terminal:

```
        building library "npymath" sources
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: legacy-install-failure

      Encountered error while trying to install package.

      numpy

      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for output from the failure.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

How do I resolve this? And am I even doing the right thing?

Comment: that shouldn't even happen. all those libraries have binary packages for windows. there should be no attempt to build anything. -- how do you "export as an exe"?

Comment: I use pyinstaller, it works fine. It's more the issue with my video not working in Cv2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Microsoft C++ Build Tools: Go to the following link and download the "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019" installer: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019

Run the installer: Once the installer has been downloaded, run it and follow the instructions to install the build tools.

Try installing numpy again: Once the build tools have been installed, try installing numpy again using pip. If the error message persists, try running the pip installation command with administrative privileges (e.g., "sudo pip install numpy" on Linux/Mac or running the command prompt as administrator on Windows).